# Amazon Web Services DynamoDB Multiple Partition Keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to have multiple partition keys in a DynamoDB table? I currently have an ID field as the partition key. Which means I can only use `get` when passing in the ID. I would like to be able to use `get` for other fields such as email, first name, last name, etc.

My current method is I do a scan of the DB and run through a loop to find the record I'm looking for. Which is not very scalable and not a good method.

Any good way to do this by either adding more partition keys or is there another method I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create [Global Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on other fields.